# How to convert JSON.NET datetime format to javascript date and time

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I can't believe I ask this kind of question. But I had to do it as I don't have much hairs left to stretch.

I am using MVC4 RC WEB API and knockout. If I call GET method of the web api, I get an object with a datetime property which was automatically converted as a string such as '2012-05-12T00:00:00' via JSON.NET.

But how can I convert this string to javascript format to use jquery ui such as calendar? I tried various methods in vain.

UPDATE: I believe it was not Date class. It was jquery calendar (and me, of course). I didn't know I had to specify minDate like this to show correct value of the date. Maybe there is better way to do it?

```
        <div class="editor-label">Date:             </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
                <input data-bind="datepicker: selectedGroup().InspectionDate, 
                      datepickerOptions: { minDate: selectedGroup().InspectionDate }">
                </input>
        </div>
```

Comment: `var d = new Date("2012-05-12T00:00:00");` doesn't work for you?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript Console (Chrome):

```
>>Date("2012-05-12T00:00:00")
Fri May 11 2012 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

`Date()` isn't working for you?

Comment: That's what I am having trouble with. It returns Today's date!

Comment: @david Creating a new Date() will get you what you want.
`new Date("2012-05-12T00:00:00")`

Answer (score 1):

2 ways really.

1. Brute-force: Split up the string, getting the year, month, day etc and call the relevant methods on javascript date such as `setYear`, `setMonth`, `setDate` etc
2. Use a library such as [date.js](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/) which tend to have better support for parsing strings to dates than the native `Date` object

This also seems to cover what you want exactly: https://github.com/csnover/js-iso8601/